# background-position with 6 values

Tags: css, css-animations

I got  the following keyframes

```
@keyframes l3 {
    20%{background-position:0%   0%, 50%  50%,100%  50%}
    40%{background-position:0% 100%, 50%   0%,100%  50%}
    60%{background-position:0%  50%, 50% 100%,100%   0%}
    80%{background-position:0%  50%, 50%  50%,100% 100%}
}
```

What these 6 numbers mean?

**My trails:**

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position) not mentioning 6 values.

Tried to play with it to understand what controls which dimension but I couldn't figure it out.

Full css sheet:

```
.loader {
    width: 60px;
    aspect-ratio: 1;
    margin-top: 5%;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
    --_g: no-repeat radial-gradient(circle closest-side,#ffffff 90%,#0000);
    background:
            var(--_g) 0%   50%,
            var(--_g) 50%  50%,
            var(--_g) 100% 50%;
    background-size: calc(100%/4) 25%;
    animation: l3 1s infinite linear;
}
@keyframes l3 {
    20%{background-position:0%   0%, 50%  50%,100%  50%}
    40%{background-position:0% 100%, 50%   0%,100%  50%}
    60%{background-position:0%  50%, 50% 100%,100%   0%}
    80%{background-position:0%  50%, 50%  50%,100% 100%}
}
```

Comment: I wrote an article about those loaders: https://css-tricks.com/single-element-loaders-the-dots/ (I have wrote that code as well)